# Adding Meta Tags to Facebook Business Page

Tags: facebook, tags, meta

I was wondering if you could help me with some instructions on adding *meta tags* to a Facebook business page so that when people type the name in Google it shows up.
At the moment they need to type the name without spaces and Facebook to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the meta tags on facebook's website. The only thing you can do to optimize your search engine visibility, would be to completely fill out your profile on your business page that is hosted on facebook.

Here are some tips to help you get the most out of your page: http://www.fansbuy.org/facebook-business-page-tips/